# Apply color interpolation on image

Tags: c++, math, image-processing, filter, interpolation

I wrote a method to apply a gradient for 3 colors to an image.
The colors are Blue->Yellow->Red.
I am getting a smooth transition in colors from yellow to red but if luminance is below 0.5 the transition from Blue -> yellow is with bumps from blue to green to yellow, so it isn't smooth at all.
I would like to have a thermal vision like effect on the image.

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, i wrote the method below.
I calculate the luminance of the original pixel to apply to the color template.

```
public void applyGradient()
{
    size = width * height;
    float r, g, b;
    float redTemp, yellowTemp, blueTemp;
    float luminance = 0;
    float result;
    index = 0;
    redTemp = 0xff000000 | (255 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 0;
    yellowTemp = 0xff000000 | (255 << 16) | (255 << 8) | 0;
    blueTemp = 0xff000000 | (0 << 16) | (0 << 8) | 255;
    while(index < size)
    {
        r = (rgbInput[index]& 0x00FF0000) >> 16;
        g = (rgbInput[index]& 0x0000FF00) >> 8;
        b = (rgbInput[index]& 0x000000FF);


    luminance = ((r+b+g)/3)/255;
    if (luminance < 0.5)
    {
        result = (float) ((yellowTemp * luminance * 2.0) +  blueTemp * (0.5 - luminance) * 2.0);
    }
    else
    {
        result = (float) (redTemp * (luminance - 0.5) * 2.0 + yellowTemp * (1.0 - luminance) * 2.0);          
    }

    output[index] = (int)result;
    index++;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the distribution of luminance, I think your problem is here:

```
if (luminance < 0.5)
{
    result = (int) ((yellowTemp * luminance * 2.0) +  blueTemp * (0.5 - luminance) * 2.0);
}
else
{
    result = (int) (redTemp * (luminance - 0.5) * 2.0 + yellowTemp * (1.0 - luminance) * 2.0);          
}
```

If luminance is less than 0.5 AND luminance is very small, then you will get blue. 
For example, if luminance is 0.0000001 then yellow will be (0.0000001 * 2.0) = 0.0000002 and blue will be ((0.5 - 0.0000001) * 2.0) = 0.9999998 which is 6 orders of magnitude more blue than yellow.

If luminance is 0.6 then red will be ((0.6 - 0.5) * 2.0) = 0.2 and yellow will be ((1.0 - 0.6) * 2.0) = 0.8 which should give you some yellow HOWEVER if your distribution of luminance is always in the tails then if luminance is 0.9 then red will be 0.8 and yellow will be 0.2. (and if luminance = 0.9999 then red will be 0.9998 and yellow 0.0002).

If you check the distribution of luminance and it is always in the tails i.e. always very small or very large, then you will not get any yellow.

On the other hand, if your distribution of luminance is Gaussian or log-normal, then I would suggest that you have an error in your yellowTemp or redTemp calculation.

Comment: I found out that if I made all variables floats then i get good yellow to red distribution if luminance is > 0.5. But if it's below and it needs to go from blue to yellow I get color bumps from blue to green to yellow. How can I smoothly go from blue to yellow :s. From yellow to red doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: Your yellow to red calculation is different from your blue to yellow calculation. Try: result = (int) ((yellowTemp * (1.0- luminance) * 2.0) +  blueTemp * (0.5 - luminance) * 2.0); or some variation of that.

Comment: not working also :(. There has to be something different when going from yellow to red and from blue to yellow. thx anyway :).

Comment: Try sending luminance to std::out when it is less than 0.5. i.e. if (luminance < 0.5) { std::cout << luminance << std::endl;} and pipe the output to a file. Open the file in LibreOffice Calc or MS Excel, and plot the values on a scatter graph. Check that the distribution is not 'clumping' and is fairly uniformly distributed.